# ArcGIS Pro freezes when using Measure tool

Tags: arcgis-pro

Every time I finish measuring the length of a line feature (specifically 500 m sections of a river) using the **Measure tool** in the Map ribbon, ArcGIS Pro **freezes up** and the swirling blue lagging cursor appears next to my mouse cursor. It takes several minutes for it to recover and in the meantime, I cannot do anything whilst I wait, including using the 'Clear Results' eraser button.

The line features have a spatial index 'FDO_Shape'

Attribute INdex: 'FDO_OBJECTID'

Data type: File Geodatabase Feature Class

Feature Type: Simple

Geometry Type: Line

This is really affecting my workoutput and I think there must be a bug in the system affecting the Measure tool.

Can anyone help fix this issue so that I can use the Measure tool without it freezing up my project?

Comment: If you export your data to shapefile, does the measure tool still lag? If possible, I would re-install the software and try again. If you're still having issues contact esri support, they should be able to better troubleshoot or pin point the issue.

Comment: If you have a lot of vertices it could snap to that could slow it down.  You might turn off other layers and zoom in.  You could also turn off snapping entirely if your streams layer is exceedingly complex.  The tool uses the same snapping settings as the rest of the project.  https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011047

Comment: What's the version of Pro? Follow the 5th trick to reset the Profile https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-desktop-installation/resetting-your-arcgis-application-profile/ta-p/913597